# Kafka data copy from one server to another

Tags: migration, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, data-migration

My kafka version is 0.8.2.
Now I want to copy data from Server A to Server B, and then expect kafka in Server B works the same as in Server A.

I try to copy all data in $log.dirs which include kafa-logs and zookeeper.
But it doesn't work.

Is it possible that just copy some data files, and then make it works fine in Server B as in Server A ?

Just like  I copy a sql dump file from production and run into my local mysql server, then it will works same as in production server.

Comment: This link may help, but copying data doesn't seem to be recommended/supported use case. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201303.mbox/%3CCAAG86fqsMzo5OYrvNERw4Dk=RMDtSMNoqLExWzu-AEHiG5h7ww@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

try kafka's kafka-mirror-maker,like this,

```
>bin/kafka-mirror-maker.sh
        --consumer.config consumer.properties
        --producer.config producer.properties --whitelist my-topic
```

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_mirror_maker

consumer.properties is server A's config,you can modify zookeeper.connect to server A's zookeeper
producer.properties is server B's config,you can modify bootstrap.servers to server B's

whitelist is topic which you want to copy from.